# FactoryGirl Dependent Object Based On Current Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I kind of have a chicken and egg type problem.  I have an Isp model  that has a default_domain _id, that I need to populate for my tests. The problem is Domain belongs to the ISP. So I am trying to figure out how to build the factory to generate an ISP

factories/isp.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :isp do
    sequence :name do |n|
      "ISP" + n.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

factories/domain.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :domain do
    isp
    account
    sequence :dn do |n|
      "foo-#{n}.com"
    end
    active :true
  end
end
```

app/models/isp.rb

```
class Isp < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :domains
  belongs_to :default_domain, class_name: 'Domain'
 end
```

app/models/domain.rb

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :isp
  ...
 end
```

I've tried using after(:create) callbacks in the factory, that just seems to create circular reference.  Tried using a block to lazily evaluate it.  Same thing.  Just at a loss where to look next or what I should try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you found a solution.  However, if you want to utilize factories to create the default_domain attribute, try this.

First, If you change your `domain` factory so that it does not reference the `isp` factory, you'll avoid the circular reference.

Second, in your `isp` factory definition, you can do this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :isp do
    sequence(:name) {|n| "ISP#{n}" }
    after_create do |isp|
      isp.default_domain = Domain.find_by_dn("#{isp.name}.com") ||
        FactoryGirl.create(:domain, :dn => "#{isp.name}.com")
      isp.save!
    end
  end
```

This will let you utilize FactoryGirl for the more complicated attributes of the `Domain` model, and if you wanted to customize the `dn` field from outside the factory, you could use transient attributes and utilize them in the `after_create` hook.

Answer (score 1):

So Of course posting it here gave me the instant boost to figure out what I was doing wrong..

Found Tip #4 of this blog post

http://randomsoftwareinklings.blogspot.com/2012/03/factory-girl-automatic-tests.html

which led me to

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :isp do
    sequence :name do |n|
      "ISP" + n.to_s
    end
    default_domain {Domain.find_or_create_by_dn("#{name}.com") }
  end
end
```

Which now works as expected.